# Assigning Values to variables in Shell scipt

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I Have parameters file which has got the data like given below

```
#host1 credentials
Host1=192.168.1.1
password=host1Password 

#host2 credentials
Host2=192.168.1.2
password=host2password
```

I want to parse through this information in the text file using shell script and assign those values to variables.

```
$host1 = 192.168.1.1
$password1 =  host1password

$host2 = 192.168.1.2
$password2 = host2password
```

I am newbie to shell scripting, please help me out to achieve this.

Comment: @hek2mgl source the file will get `password` overwritten. also spaces (if there are) could lead problem.

Comment: @Kent You are right, `source` can't be used here. Missed the fact that *password* occurs twice.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use shell scripting?  This sort of thing might be easier to understand in Python or Ruby, for example.

Comment: @ John, Actually there are four different MySQL servers, after connecting to them I have to do some joins on the data across those servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a shell that implements arrays (bash or ksh), and do this:

```
hosts=() 
passwords=()

# read the file, populate the arrays    
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do 
    case $key in 
        password) passwords+=( "$value" ) ;; 
        Host*)    hosts+=( "$value" ) ;; 
    esac
done < params

# print the contents of the arrays
for ((i=0; i < ${#hosts[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "%d\t%s\t%s\n" $i "${hosts[i]}" "${passwords[i]}"
done
```

```
0   192.168.1.1 host1Password 
1   192.168.1.2 host2password
```